Zookeeper Startup Failed: Permission Denied for Log Files:
I'm trying to set up a Kafka producer in a Spring Boot application to send messages to a specific topic. I'm getting a SerializationException. I've checked my serializer and the schema of the messages, but I can't figure out what's wrong. Any ideas?
Zookeeper wasn't successful. While the server attempted to start, there were errors encountered during the process. Here's a breakdown of the issues:

Log4j Configuration Errors: The log4j configuration seems to be missing or incorrect. There are several errors indicating missing "File" or "DatePattern" options for various appenders used for logging. These appenders define where and how Zookeeper should store log messages.
Permission Denied Errors: The server tried to access log files at specific locations but encountered permission denied errors. These locations include /home/emma_luk/kafka_2.13-3.6.1/bin/../logs/server.log, /home/emma_luk/kafka_2.13-3.6.1/bin/../logs/controller.log, and others. This suggests that the user running the Zookeeper server might not have the necessary permissions to write to these directories.
1234

I attempted to modify the log.dirs configuration in my Kafka properties file. Specifically, I changed the directory path from /tmp/kafka-logs to /tmp1/kafka-logs.
Expected Outcome:
The expectation was likely that Kafka would now store its log files in the new directory /tmp1/kafka-logs. By removing the old tmp and tmp1 directories, I might have expected to clean up any old log data.

(base) emma_luk@LAPTOP-7I41ORDC:~$ pwd
/home/emma_luk
(base) emma_luk@LAPTOP-7I41ORDC:~$ ls
0af0031518e7-key-pair.pem  Airflow.pem                  kafka.pem                  kafka_2.13-3.6.1      key.txt
0af0031518e7_dag.py        Airflow.pem:Zone.Identifier  kafka.pem:Zone.Identifier  kafka_2.13-3.6.1.tgz  miniconda3
(base) emma_luk@LAPTOP-7I41ORDC:~$ cd kafka_2.13-3.6.1
(base) emma_luk@LAPTOP-7I41ORDC:~/kafka_2.13-3.6.1$ bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties

Could you tell me why that's happening? log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/emma_luk/kafka_2.13-3.6.1/bin/../logs/server.log (Permission denied)
at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:298)
at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:237)
at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:158)


############################# Log Basics #############################

A comma separated list of directories under which to store log files
#log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
log.dirs=/var/log/kafka

in here we need a kafka directory
you can run
sudo mkdir -p /var/log/kafka
and then
sudo chmod 777 /var/log/kafka



Please learn to edit the question using the link below the post, not comments or "answers" 2) Kafka doesn't need Zookepeer; why do you?


############################# Log Basics #############################

# A comma separated list of directories under which to store log files
# log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
# added a new store log files
log.dirs=/var/log/kafka

In here we need a kafka directory. You can run:
sudo mkdir -p /var/log/kafka

and then
sudo chmod 777 /var/log/kafka

The tmp folder to which it was pointing initially is a temporary folder, so it's not very stable. You might have missed permissions or something and your kafka couldn't create logs there.
You won't need to change folders from now on.
You created a kafka folder in the /var/logs/ location and kafka is going to store logs there from now on.
What do I need to do if the folder is full again?
rm -rf /var/log/kafka/*

